# Are questions about physical applicability of noise models appropriate here?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask the following question:

> Why are physical noise processes (e.g. Johnson noise from a resistor) frequently assumed to be Gaussian processes?
>   It seems that the central limit theorem, which says that the sum of many random variables is Gaussian distributed, is not enough, because a Gaussian process not only has $x(t)$ Gaussian distributed for each $t$, but also has $x(t_1)$ and $x(t_2)$ *jointly* Gaussian for any $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Is this question appropriate for this site?
I posted [a version of it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189971/why-is-johnson-noise-a-gaussian-process) on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) but I'd like to know if the users here would welcome this type of question in the future.

Comment: In my opinion, questions like that would be welcome.

Comment: i think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Question about physical applicability of noise models are quite appropriate here.

Indeed, no actual signal or noise realization can be perfectly modeled by a particular distribution, for several reasons: discretized data, limited numbers of samples, the non-perfect behavior of the acquisition chain (nonlinearity, saturation, jitter) are common limits. For instance, the idea that an average  of $n$ uncorrelated Gaussian noises reduce in amplitude as $1\sqrt{n}$ is greatly limited by [quantization or rounded data](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jspi.2008.11.018).

A second aspect is how tractable algorithms are with a certain noise models. Sometimes, one prefers an optimal tractable model,  that may work even for other noises, because the approximation is good enough. The question  [Filtering performance on Poisson noise with quadratic data-fidelity](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25902/filtering-performance-on-poisson-noise-with-quadratic-data-fidelity/25912) was for instance related to the applicability of a Gaussian noise assumption for Poisson noises.